# converting linq to lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, repository-pattern

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). I have various tables that i am using to get my data and i am trying to use the repository pattern and linq/lambda. for example

```
 public List<tblMenu> getmainmenusclass()
        {  
            var UserInfo = GetUserInfo();
            UserType = UserInfo[0].UserTypeID;
            var menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList(); 
            if (UserType == "E")
                {
                    menus = menus.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
                }
```

Now I need to convert the code below into lambda without using .Select and have not been able to find an alternative. Since I am not using Iqueryable

```
 menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(Menus => ((Menus.IsDeleted == false) &&
                   (DataAccess.UserMenuMappings.FindByExp(UserMenuMapping => (UserMenuMapping.UserID == Global.CurrentProfile.UserID))
                   .Select(UserMenuMapping => new { MenuID = UserMenuMapping.MenuID }).Contains(new { MenuID = Menus.MenuID }) ||
                    DataAccess.RoleMenuMappings.FindByExp(RoleMenuMapping => DataAccess.UserRoleMappings.FindByExp(UserRoleMapping => (UserRoleMapping.UserID == Global.CurrentProfile.UserID))
                   .Select(UserRoleMapping => new { RoleID = UserRoleMapping.RoleID }).Contains(new { RoleID = RoleMenuMapping.RoleID }))
                   .Select(RoleMenuMapping => new { MenuID = RoleMenuMapping.MenuID }).Contains(new { MenuID = Menus.MenuID }))))
                   .Select(Menus => new { MenuID = Menus.MenuID, MenuName = Menus.MenuName });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to convert the code below into lambda"? The code already uses lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not using `IQueryable`

Yes you are - `DataAccess.Menus` is apparently an `IQueryable`, and all of the Linq extension methods you use (*and apparently `FindByExp` as well) return an `IQueryable`, so if you want to store the results in a `List<T>` you need to call `ToList()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks man. i added ToList() at the end and i have receive Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Adds.Areas.Mvc.Models.tblMenu>'

Comment: You are projecting to an anonymous type.  You can exclude the last `Select` if you just want a list of `Menu` items.